# parse.com consecutive database queries

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

I'd like to run two queries to the db - or whatever parse.com uses - consecutively.

So i have:

```
var query = Parse.Query("table1");
....

var query2 = Parse.Query("table2");
...
```

The first query is just checking some stuff to make sure that everything is ok with the request - that the device version is right etc.
The second query is the actual point of the whole exercise.

Because the first query is being asked for pretty much *all* the functions i'm using, I'd like to keep it separate. I don't really want to keep defining it for each function, and then sub-calling the second query - that's repetitive and stupid.

Is there some elegant way - ie not whiling on a boolean and setting the boolean to true in the first queries' success method - to run the two queries consecutively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I broke the queries up into two functions,

```
function1(){
    var query = Parse.Query("a");
    ...
}

function2(){
    var query = Parse.Query("b");
    ...
}
```

Then from within the success of function1() I call function2 - or rather, I call a given parameter (assuming it isn't undefined!)

```
function function1(onSuccess){
    var query = Parse.Query("a");
    query.first("c");
    query.find(){
        success : function(){
            doCoolThings();
            if (onSuccess != null){
                 onSuccess(); 
            }
        },
        error: function (){ } 
    }
}
```

And now I have a reusable component that I can use as I see fit!

BONUS: what if function2 requires paramters?

So! In the main function that calls both these two, we have:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myCoolFunction",function(request,response){ 
    var onSuccessCall = function(){ function2(request, response); };
    function1(request,response,onSuccessCall);
});

function function2(request, response){ ... }
```

with function1 defined as above.